# can someone help me to customize the toc/lof/lot margins?

Tags: table-of-contents, horizontal-alignment, titletoc

My list of figure margins is the image below

[image]

and I want like the image below

[image]

My latex code is this

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[lmargin = 2.5cm, rmargin = 2.5cm, tmargin = 2.5cm, bmargin = 3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[english,brazil]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
%\usepackage{fontspec}
%\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
%\usepackage{hyphenat} \hyp{}
%\usepackage{sectsty}
%0205218599
%\lineskip
%\setlength\afterchapskip{18pt} %capítulo começa nas páginas ímpares
\setlength{\parindent}{0.75cm}
\setstretch{1.5}
%\onehalfspacing %espaçamento entre linas
\newcommand{\signaturerule}{\rule{30em}{.4pt}}
%\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.5}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}

\setlength{\nomitemsep}{-\parsep}

\makenomenclature

\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
%\setlength{\parskip}{0.3cm} (espaço entre os parágrafos)
\titleformat{\paragraph}{\normalfont\normalsize\normalfont}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}\fontsize{12}{12}
%\titlespacing*{\paragraph}

%\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{\section*{\refname}}{}{}{}

\titleformat*{\section{\normalfont\fontfamily{phv}\fontsize{14{14}\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\normalfont\fontfamily{phv}\fontsize{12}{12}\normalfont}{}{}{}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\normalfont\fontfamily{phv}\fontsize{12}{12}\normalfont}{}{}{}

%nas figura e tabelas, mudar o nome para "FIG." e "TAB.", respectivamente
%nas equações, além da numeração colocar o termo "EQ."
\counterwithin{figure}{section}
\counterwithin{table}{section}
\counterwithin{equation}{section}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}%{subsubsection}

\graphicspath{ {figures/} }
\graphicspath{{images/}{../images/}}
\newcommand{\ii}{\'{\i}}
\newcommand{\ca}{\c{c}\~ao}
\newcommand{\co}{\c{c}\~oes}
\newcommand{\sectionbreak}{\clearpage}

\addto\captionsbrazil{\renewcommand*\contentsname{\centering SUMÁRIO}}

\addto\captionsbrazil{\renewcommand*{\listfigurename}{\centering LISTA DE ILUSTRAÇÕES}}

\addto\captionsbrazil{\renewcommand*{\listtablename}{\centering LISTA DE TABELAS}}

\titlecontents{section}[2.5em]{\addvspace{1em}\bfseries}{\contentslabel{2.9em}}{\hspace*{-2.9em}}{\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}
%\dottedcontents{section}[2.5em]{\bfseries}{2.9em}{1pc}
\dottedcontents{subsection}[2.5em]{}{3.3em}{1pc}
\dottedcontents{subsubsection}[2.5em]{}{3.3em}{1pc}


\titlecontents{figure}[0em]{\addvspace{1.5em}}{FIG.{\thecontentslabel} \hspace*{1.5em}}{}{\titlerule*[1pc]{$\cdot$}\contentspage}


\titlecontents{table}[0em]{\addvspace{1.5em}}{TAB.{\thecontentslabel} \hspace*{1.5em}}{}{ \titlerule*[1pc]{$\cdot$}\contentspage}


\renewenvironment{abstract}{\small\begin{center}\bfseries \abstractname\vspace{-.5em}\vspace{0pt}\end{center}\list{}{%\setlength{\leftmargin}{0mm}% <---------- CHANGE HERE\setlength{\rightmargin}{\leftmargin}%}%\item\relax}{\endlist}

\begin{document}
```

Is there some can help me, please?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please minimize your code example and make it compilable (MWE).

Comment: https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=31279

Comment: Every time I see `\newcommand{\ii}{\'{\i}}
\newcommand{\ca}{\c{c}\~ao}
\newcommand{\co}{\c{c}\~oes}
\newcommand{\sectionbreak}{\clearpage}` I cringe. Trying to replace real Portuguese accents with commands is the way of the dodo, and using an article class to write chapters isn't very clever either. Find a suitable class.

Answer (score 1):

```
\titlecontents{table}[0em]{\addvspace{1.5em}}{TAB.{\thecontentslabel} \hspace*{1.5em}}{}{ \titlerule*[1pc]{$\cdot$}\contentspage}
```

You have the above line in your code, but probably am looking for a modified version using `\contentspush`.

```
\titlecontents{table}[0em]{\addvspace{1.5em}}{\contentspush{TAB.~\thecontentslabel \hspace*{1.5em}}}{}{ \titlerule*[1pc]{$\cdot$}\contentspage}
```

Comment: Thanks Johannes_B. Your comment was the way that I wanted!!

Answer (score 0):

What you want is the default for the `article`, `report`, `book` etc. classes. Something in the packages you have used (unlikely) or in your code has changed this. Being a GOM (Grumpy Old Man) I'm not going to plough through your preamble. However...

Create a MWE like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
 % your preamble
\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\begin{figure}
\centering
ILLUSTRATION
\caption{A long caption that requires more than one line ...}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

and then keep reducing the packages and code in your preamble until the LoF reverts to the default. Your problem is with the last deleted item(s).

Alternatively use the optional argument to `\caption`:

```
\caption[Short version for LoF}{A long caption that requires more than one line ...}
```